# unable to copy files from Amazon S3 even with region specified

Tags: amazon-s3, command-line-interface, ls, cp

First off: I'm new to using the `aws cli`:
I've got problems to copy files from amazon S3 using the `aws cli`, while `aws s3 ls` works as expected and shows me all the buckets,
 `$ aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/subdir/* /patch/to/local/dir/ --region us-east-2 --source-region us-east-2` keeps barking at me with 
`A client error (301) occurred when calling the HeadObject operation: Moved Permanently` - when I log into S3 using the AWS website, I get "us-east-2" in the urls while it displays **US West (Oregon)** on the side. I've also tried the above with both regions set to `us-west-2` but that didn't work either. What may be going on here and how do I get the files copied correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to download data from s3 bucket. Firstly configure aws-cli using:

```
aws configure
```

Once configured, use s3 sync command, this will download all sub directries locally.

```
aws s3 sync s3://mybucket/subdir/ /patch/to/local/dir/
```

As you are using s3 cp command, use it as

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/subdir/ /patch/to/local/dir/ --recursive
```